# How to see inner structure of an object in blender game engine?

Tags: game-engine, objects, transparency

My goal is to be able to look the inside structure of a complex object in blender game engine. For this, I am writing a python code that enables me to change the transparency of the object while playing. I activated the transparency (z-transparency) in the material tab and I set the backface culling = false.
Now, when I start the game you can see parts of the inside structure of the object even if I set the alpha value equal to 1.
Here are 2 samples tho show what I mean. Transparency mode on the left is set to: *Opaque*, on the right image is *Alpha Sort*:
[image: Transparency mode: Opaque] [image: Transparency mode: Alpha Sort]

Changing the transparency mode to alpha sort, hides much more the inner structure. But you can still see open parts that let you look inside the object. Why does this happen? What I would like to see is more something like this
[image: Transparency deactivated]
When I change the transparency value of the object, I should be able to see more and more through the object, thus showing the inner structure of it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: set the view port display to GLSL, that should fix you problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I changed my view port display to GLSL and I got the same result

Comment: @simonwiedemann you could publish your script to be able to experiment with what you have done and see if I can understand how to do what you want to get